# htaccess to redirect url with params

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have to redirect a url to another url with all its parameters using htaccess.

My incoming url will be something like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/book-it.jsp?id=3&var1=values&var2=value2...
```

and I want to get it in PHP (`book-it.php`) as something like this (with all its parameters):

```
www.mydomain.com/book-it.php?id=3&var1=values&var2=value2...
```

I was using JSP and from now on moving to PHP and we need to use same URL since this url is already published with my application and I can't change that now. I need to get that url and parameters to another file.

Comment: Do you need redirect rule for this particular URL .. or for all JSP pages?

Comment: Only to this JSP url *www.mydomain.com/book-it.jsp* which should redirect to some other php file with all its parameters.

Comment: One more question: as I understand it should be rewrite (internal redirect) or proper redirect (when URL changes in browser)?

Comment: Yes, It is redirect. *www.mydomain.com/book-it.jsp?id=3&var1=values&var2=value2* exactly i wil get this and i want it to goto *www.mydomain.com/book-it.php?id=3&var1=values&var2=value2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 main approaches:

1) Using [Redirect directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
Redirect 301 /book-it.jsp http://www.mydomain.com/book-it.php
```

2) Using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) module (this needs to be placed in **.htaccess** in website root folder. If placed in Apache config file (inside `<VirtualHost>`, for example) the rules need to be modified slightly):

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^book-it\.jsp$ http://www.mydomain.com/book-it.php [QSA,NC,R=301,L]
```

Both of them will preserve query string.